# Function not outputting

Tags: c++

I'm trying to sort an array, but somehow the program doesn't output anything?
I tried writing the good old for in for sorting algorithm, doesn't work, then I tried STL, still doesn't work. Here's the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

void in(int n, int v[]){
    cin>>n;
    for(int i=1; i<=n; i++){
        cin>>v[i];
    }
}
void sortf(int &n, int v[]){
    sort(v+1, v+n+1);
}
void af(int n, int v[]){
    for(int i=1; i<=n; i++){
        cout<<v[i]<<" ";
    }
}

int main(){
    int n, v[1001];
    in(n, v);
    sortf(n, v);
    af(n, v);
}
```

Comment: In `sortf(int &n, int v[])` you pass `n` by reference, allthoug you don't need to.  In `void in(int n, int v[])` you pass by value, allthough you need a reference here. Voting to close as typo.

Comment: Why not use [`std::sort`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort)? What does "doesn't work" mean?

Comment: @tadman Actually `std::sort` is used in the function `sortf()`. `using namespace std;` is considered as a bad habit...

Comment: you are using 1-based indices by having loops starting at 1 and perform the last iteration with `n` ( `==` size). Thats surprising, uncommon, and even if correct now likely to cause problems later. Better use 0-based indices (ie `for (int i=0; i<n;++i)`)

Answer (score 1):

The variable `n` in `main()` is **copied** to the argument `int n` of the function `in()` and changes to the argument inside the function `in()` will not affect the variable `n` in `main()`.

Because of that, `sortf()` and `af()` are using value of `n`, which is uninitialized and indeterminate.

To have functions modify caller's variables, you should use references.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

void in(int& n, int v[]){ // add & to make n reference
    cin>>n;
    for(int i=1; i<=n; i++){
        cin>>v[i];
    }
}
void sortf(int &n, int v[]){
    sort(v+1, v+n+1);
}
void af(int n, int v[]){
    for(int i=1; i<=n; i++){
        cout<<v[i]<<" ";
    }
}

int main(){
    int n, v[1001];
    in(n, v);
    sortf(n, v);
    af(n, v);
}
```

Comment: Hello MikeCAT. I spent 3 hours to figure out why my code didn't work. However, I am stupid and I forgot to add &, thanks for pointing that out, you just saved my keyboard from being smashed.